# Google Maps Xpath using Google Spreadsheet IMPORTXML

Tags: google-maps, xpath, google-maps-api-3, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to use Pull data from google maps results using IMPORTXML function in google spreadsheet but I am getting error #N/A

=importxml(http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cosmetic+surgeon+NEAR+New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States&output=classic&dg=ntvb,"//div[@class='name lname'])

or

=importxml(http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cosmetic+surgeon+NEAR+New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States&output=classic&dg=ntvb,//SPAN[@class='pp-place-title'])

but nothing is working..  Any thoughts???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to give importxml literal strings as arguments, they need to be double-quoted:

`=importxml("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cosmetic+surgeon+NEAR+New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States&output=classic&dg=ntvb", "//div[@class='name lname']")`

Comment: Thanks for reply, sorry while pasting i forgot to add double quote. . well it doesn't work in that way too.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the #N/A, you should see an error message.  What's it say?

Comment: If I hover my mouse over the #n/a, is saying " The content is empty" whereas it's not correct . .

Comment: @RebeccaGoodwin `IMPORTXML()` can only evaluate XPath expressions against the raw source HTML of a page - almost all content on that page is generated by Javascript.

Comment: Thank Mathias! Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: also, Is there any way we could force google speadsheet to keep loading until the data gets available as I have seen in most of cases where spreadsheet return #n/a first time and if we try it again on new another speadsheet it started to pull data. Cn we also use same importxml function in excel file using VBA, any script do you know about. . . your help and guideline will be much appreciated. . Thanks!!!!!!