# Get Google Reviews with IMPORTXML function in G Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import to a Google Sheet the number of reviews and average rating of a certain venue on Google Maps.

Taking as an example this page:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?cid=8807257593070771217
```

From Chrome's inspector, the XPath for the average should be:

`//*[@id='pane']/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[1]/span/span`

However it always returns empty.

Any idea why?

PS - This URL redirects to another, but that shouldn't be the problem as the same thing happens with Facebook and it returns the correct values.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Xpath using Google Spreadsheet IMPORTXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313012/google-maps-xpath-using-google-spreadsheet-importxml)

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313012/google-maps-xpath-using-google-spreadsheet-importxml), you can't. If you want to scrape Google Maps, use Google's officially supported way to do that: their APIs.

You're probably interested in the [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), in particular.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a businesses Google My Business page you can leverage the API to pull in reviews that way: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data

Otherwise, https://serpapi.com can scrape Google reviews for you.